# Running an action creator in response to an action (without saga)

Tags: redux

Is there a library for redux that allows a function to be run in response to a specific action type and have that function's return value (which may be an action/thunk/promise) dispatched? I know that saga allows for this, but saga is a bit full featured for this basic requirement.

I understand that this would be fairly trivial to write myself, but if someone else has already done it then there's no need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I would write my own middleware like this:

```
export default ({ dispatch }) => (next) => (action) => {
  if (action.type === 'MY_ACTION') {
    const anotherAction = someOtherFunction();
    dispatch(anotherAction); // can use next() if you want to skip all middleware before this one.
  } else {
    next(action);
  }
}
```